# Integrate Stripe Checkout with R Shiny App

Tags: r, stripe-payments, shiny

[cross post with the R shiny Google group - I waited 24 hours]

The following code will render the `checkout` button from Stripe normally if I simply save it as a `.html` and open it with Firefox:

```
<h1> this is a test </h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_qdunoptxl9KNXR5qk7WdtkVg"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

but placing it in a R Shiny app like so:

```
output$StripeCheckOut <- renderUI({
  div(class="span6", 
     div(HTML('
                <h1> this is a test </h1>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                  <script
                   src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                   data-key="pk_test_qdunoptxl9KNXR5qk7WdtkVg"
                   data-amount="2000"
                   data-name="Demo Site"
                   data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
                   data-image="/128x128.png">
                 </script>
               </form>
            ')))
```

will result in a blank field under the `This is a Test` text.

It seems that R Shiny is not allowing the Javascript to dynamically load the button after the page has been rendered by the dom.

How can I include the basic Stripe Checkout button in an R Shiny App?

Comment: before going too deep into this, did you try to move to an HTML-based site that integrates Shiny (vs use the HTML UI element function calls from a raw Shiny app)? http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#html-ui has info on how to do it that way which makes it much easier to integrate more dynamic content.

Comment: Yes, putting the html into `ui.r` didn't change anything. For various reasons I can't switch this project to a pure `index.html` base!

Comment: (code in comment wasn't working. see the "answer" but it's more of just a way to show a possible alternative way to specify the `script` element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I include:

```
 HTML('
        <h1> this is a test </h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          <script
           src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
           data-key="pk_test_qdunoptxl9KNXR5qk7WdtkVg"
           data-amount="2000"
           data-name="Demo Site"
           data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
           data-image="/128x128.png">
          </script>
        </form>
       ')
```

inside `ui.r` directly, it works - but placing it inside a conditional panel will not allow the Stripe JS to load.

Instead, I used an html `data-display-if` condition:

```
<div align="center" data-display-if="output.Unpaid==True">
...
</div>
```

and everything worked!

This is also nice because it allows you to bind the condition to a Shiny `output` object vs `input` object which can be easier at times to work with.

---

**Update after further testing**

It turns out my edits don't quite work; after the Stripe Checkout JS has loaded, it blocks my Shiny App from interacting with other JS elements on the page.

It seems like there is some conflict with the Stripe JS and the internal Shiny JS....

---

**New Update**

The newest version of Shiny (0.9.1) has fixed this problem.
It seems to have been something with js heads and singletons, which have been updated in the most recent release.

This is no longer an issue, 
and you can now use Stripe directly in shiny.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that didn't work in a comment either (bad luck with code in comments this week). Did you try wrapping it in an explicit `tags$script` call?

```
tags$script(src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js", 
            class="stripe-button", 
            "data-key"="pk_test_qdunoptxl9KNXR5qk7WdtkVg",
            "data-amount"="2000",
            "data-name"="Demo Site",
            "data-description"="2 widgets ($20.00)",
            "data-image"="/128x128.png")
```

it might be advantageous to build the whole form that way to see if it helps.

Comment: This did not work for me inside `server.R`, but I didn't test it within `ui.R`